# Docusaurus make full page background gradient

Tags: css, docusaurus

I've just started to create a new project by using Docusaurus and have tried to change background of home page to linear gradient. However, couldn't make it. I can change the navbar and the footer colors seperately, but how to make the background of the page like shown in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of anyone wondering the result, I could solve the problem. By using the [swizzling](https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling) as stated in docusaurus documentation;
run `npm run swizzle`, and choose the *Layout* component in order to eject or wrap. The Layout folder will be visible to you under src/theme/ directory. You can edit the html,body style in styles.modules.css file to change the all background of the pages.